# Primefaces File Upload won't upload files greater than 1 MB

Tags: java, tomcat, primefaces

[image: The upload event would stall at this point only]

**Primefaces don't allow me to upload a file greater than 1 MB as shown in the picture. The code works on my local tomcat server but would not work on the Amazon prod tomcat server. Any suggestions please I even used maxPostSize but it does not work. I guess the issue is with the server.xml as the code works fine. **

**Server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
<!--
  <Connector compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,image/png,image/jpeg,font/woff2,text/css; chartset=utf8,text/html;charset=UTF-8"  compression="on" compressionMinSize="256" connectionTimeout="20000" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
  -->
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               maxPostSize="-1"
               redirectPort="8443" />
   
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

***File Upload Handler***

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

        UploadedDocument doc = new UploadedDocument();

        try {
            doc.setDoc(IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    event.getFile().getFileName() + " could not be uploaded.", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
        doc.setDocName(event.getFile().getFileName());
        if (temporaryUploadedDocuments == null) {
            temporaryUploadedDocuments = new ArrayList<UploadedDocument>();
        }
        
        temporaryUploadedDocuments.add(doc);

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                event.getFile().getFileName() + " has been uploaded.", null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

        count = count + 1;
    }
```

***File upload button***

```
<p:fileUpload style="word-break: break-all;"
                                                            update="dtaAttachments"
                                                            fileUploadListener="#{AccountComponent.handleFileUpload}"
                                                            mode="advanced" sizeLimit="10000000" multiple="false"
                                                            fileLimit="5"
                                                            fileLimitMessage="Please zip if you have more than 5 files."
                                                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|docx|doc|png|jpg|jpeg|png|rar|zip|PDF|DOCX|DOC|PNG|JPG|JPEG|RAR|ZIP|xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX|txt|eml)$/">
                                                        </p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: That is definitely your issue a max post sizing issue where Amazon or Tomcat is blocking that at 1MB.  I know this because Jboss does the same thing and its fixed with a configuration setting.

Comment: @Melloware What configuration has to be done?

Comment: Not sure i know in Jboss its max-post-size i am not sure with TOmcat/Amazon you are using.  But that is definitely your issue and not a PrimeFaces issue. The 1MB is being stopped by your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post issue has been resolved. The issue was not with my tomcat. I had a Nginx server running blocking all uploads above 1 MB. To resolve this, just set this paramter in block below in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. This will allow uploads upto 100 Mb

```
http {

    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```